# Printing int array contents after filling in input shows only 0

Tags: java, arrays

First I input values to the array, and the values are stored correctly.

Later, when I print the values of the array on the second loop, it shows zeros for all values. I don't know why?

```
   import java.util.*;

    class SumOfInt{
    public static void main(String args[]){ 
    int n=1,i=0,sum=0,k;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);      

    for(i=0,n=1;i<n;i++,n++){
        int numarr[]=new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        numarr[i]=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("numarr["+i+"]: " +numarr[i]);               
            if(numarr[i]==(-999)){                  
                for(k=0;k<n-1;k++){
                    System.out.println("numarr["+k+"]: " +numarr[k]);  \\it shows zero even after i gave it a value above
                    sum=sum+numarr[k];
                }                   
                System.out.println(sum);
                break;
            }
    }       
  } 
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Enter a number:
12
numarr[0]: 12
Enter a number:
13
numarr[1]: 13
Enter a number:
14
numarr[2]: 14
Enter a number:
-999
numarr[3]: -999
numarr[0]: 0
numarr[1]: 0
numarr[2]: 0
0
```

Comment: you redefine the array in every outer loop

Comment: Use a debugger to find your problem

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
for(i=0,n=1;i<n;i++,n++){
    int numarr[]=new int[n];
```

Creates a completely **new** array each time you re-enter that loop!

Instead, you should go for something like this:

- ask the user how many numbers he wants to enter (say *n*)
- create an appropriately sized array with *n* slots
- iterate those *n* slots and ask the user for input
- store the input, compute sum on the way
- print sum and maybe iterate the array again to print numbers

If you *have* to support a variable number of entries - create an array with say 1000 empty slots upfront. *Once*.

Beyond that: *separate* concerns. There is no point in putting the second loop into the first one. Instead: have *one* loop collecting input; and a second *disjunct* loop for your output. Your solution is much more complicated than it ought to be.

As the OP asks to really **grow** the array, the solution looks a bit different:

- start with an initial array, maybe size 10
- whenever the user adds a new number: check if it there is still a free slot in the array. If not: a) create a new bigger array b) copy all entries into the new array c) continue working with the new array

Comment: but i want it's length to be self increasing, until -999 is entered i.e User can enter any number of values,even more than 1000 number of values.

Comment: I guess: no human user would be willing to put up 1000 numbers manually. But see my updates. Your approach is missing a crucial fact: you cant increase an array but just creating a new one. You create a new one ... and copy over the items from the old one!